# NVIDIA on Centos/RHEL 8 - driver installed but not used

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, kernel-modules, nouveau

I'm using CentOS 8. I've enabled the CUDA repositories for RHEL 8, and have installed the NVIDIA driver (and CUDA).

However - it isn't being used. Before doing anything else, nouveau is used for the X server; which precludes the driver from loading IIANM. If I run `nvidia-xconfig`, to get X to use the NVIDIA driver - nouveau is no longer used, but neither is the NVIDIA driver, and I can't even load X.

What do I do?

Notes:

- I've found [several](https://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/installing-nvidia-drivers-rhel-centos-7/) [suggestions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-centos-8) to manually install the drivers; I'd rather avoid that if possible and stick to the distribution's packages.
- Also noticed [this guide](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA?highlight=%28CategoryHowto%29#Current_GeForce.2FQuadro.2FTesla), which does use the CentOS packages - but it's pretty old and outdated; filenames and package names don't match what's available on CentOS 8.

Comment: Any luck on this?  I have the same problem, and same preference to stick with package manager packages.